# Bond/ReactiveKit - Temporarily suspend observing events and start observing again (but see events that were missed)

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactivekit

I'm starting to use Bond to implement a basic MVVM pattern in an app and have a scenario where I would like to temporarily suspend the observing of events on an `Observable` (via a flag).

I would then like to resume the observing of events, but also want to "replay/resend" the events to my observers which may have been missed during the suspension period.

I have found the `pausable(by:)` function on an `Observable` which works well for the temporary suspension of the observing of events, but am not sure how to "replay/resend" any events after reenabling the observation.

An cut-down example of what I'm trying to do is this :-

- Initially set the value of `viewModel.message` to be "Original Value"
- On `viewDidLoad` bind `viewModel.message` to the text of `label`, but allow it to be pausable.
- On the UI have some buttons that will

  - Change the value of message (`changeMessageButton`)
  - Stop updating the label text (`stopChangingLabelTextButton`)
  - Start updating the label text again (`startChangingLabelTextButton`)

Code :-

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let viewModel = MyViewModel()
    let shouldUpdate = Observable(true)

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var changeMessageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopChangingLabelTextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startChangingLabelTextButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       viewModel.message.pausable(by: shouldUpdate).bind(to: label.bnd_text)

       changeMessageButton.bnd_tap.observe { _ in
           viewModel.message.value = "Changing Message"
       }

       stopChangingLabelTextButton.bnd_tap.observe { _ in
           shouldUpdate.value = false
       }

       startChangingLabelTextButton.bnd_tap.observe { _ in
           shouldUpdate.value = true
           // DO SOMETHING TO BE ABLE TO "REPLAY/RESEND" ANY EVENTS TO viewmodel.message 
       }
    }
}

class MyViewModel {
   let message = Observable<String>("Original Value")
}
```

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `pausable` will ignore and omit events during the paused state. If you're ok with replaying only the latest value, you could flat map `shouldUpdate` like this:

```
shouldUpdate.flatMapLatest { shouldUpdate -> SafeSignal<String> in 
    if shouldUpdate {
      return viewModel.message.toSignal()
    } else {
      return .never()
    }
}.bind(to: label.bnd_text)
```

Whenever `shouldUpdate` emits an event, it will either start propagating `viewModel.message` or nothing. Whenever it starts propagating `viewModel.message` it will also receive latest value since Observable always replays latests to new observers.

Please make sure you do `import ReactiveKit`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - it was exactly what I was looking for!